# Select a non significant div tag using jsoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm using jsoup for webscraping and have run into another issue. The div I need information from has no class, id or any special indication. It's buried in the page. Here it is:

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="form-label">Rate: </div>
    <div>11.082/11.167</div>
    <div class="form-label padding-top">High/Low: </div>  
    <div>1005.0/0.0004</div>
</div>
```

I need to get the 1st set of numbers but I'm not sure how I can tell jsoup I want them specifically; does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `doc` is your Document object...

```
doc.select('.column > div:eq(1)');
```

should do the job, you basically select the parent div by class, then get all child div's, but filter the child div's so that the element at index 1 is returned (this is a zero based index, so index 1 is the 2nd element)

Personally, i'd switch to jQuery as it uses a far better selector engine, but each to their own...

Comment: I'll see if that works. I'm only using jsoup because a colleague suggested it.

Comment: I'm assuming this is wrong...  System.out.println(doc.select("column > div:eq(1)"));

Comment: The `.select()` returns the element as an object, to get the text inside add `.text()` after it, so it becomes `.select(xxx).text()`

Comment: It returned "BUX/TIX 10.872/0.0000". Apparently there are two cases in which the column class is used with the divs. And it's awfully wierd that the rate is 00 right now but that's nothing to do with my code :P Any ideas on how to get the 2 numbers out of the string?

Comment: I used this code to get what I wanted:  String a[] = rawRate.split("\\s+");
  String b[] = a[1].split("/");
  Rates[0] = Float.parseFloat(b[0]);
  Rates[1] = Float.parseFloat(b[1]);
  
  System.out.println(Rates[0] + ":" + Rates[1]);

Answer (score 1):

1. Select all divs with `class="column"`
2. Loop through your list of selected elements. Select the first div inside your element that has the text `Rate:`
3. your Text is inside the 2. div

Sorry Code formatting isnt working o.0

```
public String getRage(Document document) {
    for(Element e : document.getElementsByClass("column")) {
        if(e.getElementsByTagName("div").get(0).ownText().equals("Rate: ")) {
            return e.getElementsByTagName("div").get(1).ownText();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Um, do you think you could give me a bit of syntax? I'll try my own but I'm fairly new to web-scraping, especially with jsoup.

Comment: I don't have the code. You should try and debug on which stage the code isn't working.